# can't use plot(kind='kde') in spyder

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, spyder

The code is easy, but it caused the kernel to die, and the error is mentioned in the second image. I tried my best to figure it out, but did not succeed. If you have a suggestion or the solution, please tell me. Thank you very much.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ser = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000))
ser.plot(kind='kde')

Kernel died, restarting


/home/flowqer/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py:84: UserWarning: Config option `use_jedi` not recognized by `IPCompleter`.
self.config = config
```

Comment: Is this reproducible or a one-off event?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I can't reproduce this problem (i.e. my kernel doesn't die after running that code). Please try to update Pandas and Numpy and try again.